# Python statsmodels Q-Qplot: TypeError: %s requires more parameters to compute ppf

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

I am trying to do a [Q-Q plot in Python using statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html). I want to use a geometric distribution and compare my data against that.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy
from scipy import stats
```

```py
s1 = np.random.geometric(0.01, size=1000)
sm.qqplot(data=s1, line="45", dist=scipy.stats.geom)
plt.show()
```

throws the following error:

`TypeError: %s requires more parameters to compute ppf`

I think it may be related to parameters needed by the distribution. If instead of `geom` I use `expon` it does work, however my data is discrete hence i would like `geom`. How can I solve this? There doesnt seem to be a way to include `kwargs` in the [qqplot](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html) function.

Comment: The docstring lists `distargs` as arguments for the distribution (`args`, and not `kwargs`)

Comment: How could I not see this... Anyway, thank you. Do you want to leave this as answer? If not I will do it myself